# Getting FlyWay Exception while migrating springboot version

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

Getting the below exception while migrating my project from Sprinn boot version 1.1.1 to 2.3.12 Release.

```
2022-02-08 19:28:15 WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V001_01__create_tables.sql failed
-------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ICNCCOCN.ICNRQTCV_QUOTATION_COVERAGE (
QTCV_UUID                     VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
QTCV_TENANTID                 VARCHAR(2),
QTCV_QTTN_UUID                VARCHAR(36),
QTCV_COVERAGECODE             VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
QTCV_CONTINGENT               INTEGER,
QTCV_CHANGED_ON               TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
QTCV_CHANGED_BY               VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT ICNSQTCV_P PRIMARY KEY(QTCV_UUID),
)[*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the syntax in `V001_01__create_tables.sql` file. Please share it

Comment: Unrelated, but: UUID values should be stored in a column with the data type `uuid` not in a `varchar` column.

Comment: You have a dangling `,` after the PK definition. Remove that.

Comment: yes after remvoing the error gone, but after every mvn clean install dangling , is coming...

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) on projectcore: Cannot create resource output directory:    --> this exception am getting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

After removing the dangling issue got resolved..